# How to append/concat dataframes from within a function to a global dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a scraping function that returns a dataframe as such:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDtQJ.png)

How can i add this dataframe to a global dataframe as to keep extending my dataframe like so:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9hfv.png)

The result should be a function i can run again and again with different arguments to compile data into my dataframe.

`

```
def getTicketPrices(IPLocation, X, Y):
    
    #Scraping...
    
    df = pd.DataFrame (price_list_cleaned, columns = [IPLocation])
```

`

I have tried creating a dataframe before the function as such:
`resultsDF = pd.DataFrame()`

and then using trying to use the .concat() method within the function but it returns an empty dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat`:

```
appended_df  = pd.DataFrame() # Initilize
appended_df = pd.concat([appended_df, new_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: but wouldnt the next time i run the function 'override' the current dataframe?

Comment: No. It will every time add more columns to 'appended_df'

Comment: can you clarify, because this returns 
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'appended_df' referenced before assignment"
Am i to initialize 'appended_df  = pd.DataFrame()'
Before or within the function, i feel like i have tried both.

Comment: Nvm! I fixed it using the 'global' method on 'appended_df' at the start of my function.